# Unable to upgrade a kernel module using modprobe: after reboot dmesg indicates the old version (but modinfo shows the new one)

Tags: ubuntu, upgrade, kernel-modules, modprobe

I cannot [upgrade `e1000e` driver](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/network-and-i-o/ethernet-products/000005480.html) in Ubuntu 16.04.  At least not according to the output of `dmesg` after reboot.

After downloading the latest version 3.3.4 and running `make install` in the `src/` directory, I did

```
sudo modprobe -r e1000e
sudo modprobe e1000e
```

After rebooting Ubuntu, I checked the output of `dmesg | grep e1000e`, and there was a line

```
[    1.289423] e1000e: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Driver - 3.2.6-k
```

which, I suppose, meant that I still had the old version of the module.

However, the output of `modinfo -F version e1000e` was

```
3.3.4-NAPI
```

I repeated

```
sudo modprobe -r e1000e
sudo modprobe e1000e
```

and the output of `dmesg | grep e1000e` now contained two lines

```
[    1.289423] e1000e: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Driver - 3.2.6-k
...
[  928.971079] e1000e: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Driver - 3.3.4-NAPI
```

After another reboot the story is the same: I only see `3.2.6-k` in `dmesg`.

What is going on?  Why is the version `3.2.6-k` not removed completely?  How should I upgrade a kernel module properly?

**UPDATE**

I have tried to execute additionally `update-initramfs -u`.  Now the version appearing in `dmesg` output after reboot is the new one, but it seems that I have "tainted" the kernel:

```
$ dmesg | grep e1000e
[    4.224225] e1000e: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
[    4.231980] e1000e: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Driver - 3.3.4-NAPI
...
```

Comment: The module is probably also present in the initramfs filesystem, and you need to replace it there. Look for the `dracut` command.

Comment: ["How to update initramfs/dracut with a newer module?"](https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=3162) on CentOS forum seems related, but i have not yet figured out a solution in my case...

Comment: I've found a [question about "tainting kernel"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24975377) on SO.

Comment: Probably i need to follow [these instructions](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/module-signing.txt) on kernel.org for signing a kernel module, but it is a bit complicated.  Maybe i will just wait and hope that the driver will get updated with a kernel update.

Comment: A tainted kernel shouldnt stop you from using it. It just means you cannot expect any support from the community in case of problems, which you shouldnt have if it is just a signing problem.